# FTPSClient, What values to give for Remote and Local

Tags: java, ftps

I am new to FTPSClient i trying to connect to a FTPS created in my laptop. i don't exactly what some of the methods working and their parameter meaning.
For example,
In my code i have created a FTPSClient as below:

```
FTPSClient ftps =new FTPSClient();
```

Then connected to a server use connect() method with ip address.

```
ftps.connect("172.xx.xx.xxx");
```

After every step i will check the reply code using.

```
ftps.getReplyCode();
```

In the below code i know that
username = system username 
password = the password to login

```
ftps.login(username, password);
```

In the my system in Internet Information Service(IIS). Created an ftp server with ssl and given the below directory to share.

```
C:\Users\karan-pt2843\Desktop\FTPS
```

Want to send the file in below directory to the server.

```
D:\sam.txt
```

Now i want to store a file in the server in the given above directory and i tried using

```
remote="";
local="";
InputStream input;
input = new FileInputStream(local);
ftps.storeFile(remote, input);
input.close();
```

I don't know what value to give for remote and local. please help me with the values to give on them and the what happens internal.

Comment: you mean `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient`?

Comment: yes, I meant org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.

Comment: Did you read https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_2_2/src/main/java/examples/ftp/FTPSExample.java ?

Comment: Yes, But i didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Use passive mode as default because most of us are
    // behind firewalls these days.
    ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ...
    String remote = "samFromClient.txt"; //Place on FTP
    String input = "D:/sam.txt"          //Place on your Client
    //Your FTP reads from the inputstream and store the file on remote-path
    InputStream input = new InputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
    ftps.storeFile(remote, input);
    input.close();
    ftps.logout();
    ...
```

Taken from: [Apache example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_2_2/src/main/java/examples/ftp/FTPSExample.java)

Comment: Thanks the connection is successful. but it shows different error.

Comment: `ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));`
Add this line and there should be more output on your console.
Which error?

Comment: 'FTPSs
220 Microsoft FTP Service
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
Connected to 172.24.100.113.
USER karan-pt2843
331 Password required
PASS Nivedhaav@1
230 User logged in.
SYST
215 Windows_NT
Remote system is Windows_NT
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (172,24,100,113,214,42).
STOR samFromClient.txt
534-Policy requires SSL.
 Win32 error:   Access is denied. 
 Error details: SSL policy requires SSL for data channel.
534 End
QUIT
221 Goodbye.'

Comment: `String protocol = "SSL";    // SSL/TLS` and in the constructor.
`ftps = new FTPSClient(protocol);`

Comment: @karanbabub STOR samFromClient.txt 534-Policy requires SSL. Win32 error. It seems that the error is on server side. You use ssl. Try to change the `"samFromClient.txt"` and check the rights of the user `karan-pt2843`.  Check the log of your ftp.

Comment: where to check that?

Comment: I'm not an administrator. Sorry. The configuration of your ftp has to be changed.
Try to connect via ftp-tool like filezilla...

Comment: What to change in ftp configuration ?

Comment: I added this code after logging in `c.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
c.execPBSZ(0);  // Set protection buffer size
c.execPROT("P"); // Set data channel protection to private
c.enterLocalPassiveMode();`  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good job. What was the problem?